# Creating a note in a Evernote linked notebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, evernote

I have some issue creating a **note** in a **linked notebook** with the **iOS evernote SDK**.

I've tried to simply get the noteStore in question by

```
EvernoteNoteStore* noteStore = [EvernoteNoteStore noteStoreForLinkedNotebook:self.linkedNotebook];
```

I've then attempted to create a note with

```
[noteStore createNote:note success:success failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
```

This always ends in an error saying I don't have permission to create the note.

I have further tried to authenticate with the shared key in my linked notebook but have  there also been stopped with the same error in the failure block.

```
[noteStore authenticateToSharedNotebookWithShareKey:self.linkedNotebook.shareKey success:^(EDAMAuthenticationResult *result) {
        [noteStore createNote:note success:success failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
```

How can I go about the issue of creating a note in a linked notebook?

Answer (score 0):

OK. So if your permissions are correct, I guess there's an error in the process.
I just published a blog post on this : http://laurent.sarrazin.io/2014/05/evernote-api-create-notes-in-a-linked-notebook.html It's in PHP but the process would be the same in other languages.

I guess you're not setting the notebook guid when creating the note. You can obtain this guid by calling the [getSharedNotebookByAuth](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore.getSharedNotebookByAuth) method. Don't use the linked notebook guid ! It would result in an EDAMNotFoundException.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you have the right permissions ? i.e. write permissions on the notebook.

Comment: It's shared with 'modify and invite others' option. Which seems to be the highest permission I can share a notebook with.